# to display doc file in text format asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to read content of file.but these code is not helping.

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path); this line is giving error.

protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            strbuild.Append(s);
            strbuild.AppendLine();
        }
        textBoxContents.Text = strbuild.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: which type of file u r reading (*.txt?)

Comment: Do you want to read the file at the time of uploading?

Comment: I want to read doc file.help me

Comment: What do you mean `read doc file`? Doc is a binary file and cannot be read as text. Please explain in more detail what it is you want to do and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File.ReadAllText` function expects the file to exist on the specified location. You haven't saved it on the server and yet you are attempting to read it. If you don't need to save the uploaded file on the server you could read directly from the input stream.

```
protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileupload1.PostedFile != null && fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileupload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            textBoxContents.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

This will work for text files. If you want to parse some other formats such as Word documents you will need a library to do that.

Comment: thnks this is working for text file.now plz tel me code to read doc file.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"..\asd.txt");
for (i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
System.Console.WriteLine("Contents = " + lines[i]);
}
```